# Не хочет работать on click function в jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не работает событие `click` в *jQuery*. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем я ошибся и где не доглядел:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("btn-transparent").on("click", function(){
    $(".well").css("background-color", "red !important");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

   <h2 class="text text-center"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"> </i> Hey, what when and why there is no and yes?</h2>


   <p class="author">-Alina Khachatrian</p>



<div class="buttons">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a id="tweet-quote" title="Tweet current quote" target="_blank" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
</a> 
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-transparent" id ="getNewQuote" title="Get a new quote">New Quote</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <footer class="text-center">
   <hr>
   <p>Written and coded by <a href="https://github.com/edkiljak">Edgar Kiljak</a>.</p>
   </footer>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Забыли поставить точку в селекторе:

```
  $(".btn-transparent")
```

Comment: Спасибо, после исправления все равно не хочет работать.

Comment: `$(".well").css("background-color", "red");` вот так работает

Answer (score 3):

btn-transparent - класс

В селекторе с точки начать надо

```
$(".btn-transparent")
```

Comment: Спасибо, после исправления все равно не хочет работать.

Comment: `$(".well").css("background-color", "red");` вот так работает

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно вызываете метод `.css()`. Правильно было бы сделать так:

```
$('.selector').css('background', 'red');
```

> http://api.jquery.com/css/
>
> **Note:** `.css()` ignores !important declarations. So, the statement `$( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" )` does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.